# Remove the text from label after submitting data to database

Tags: asp.net, forms, submit

I have this code in the button click event. The issue is I want to show the text "Thread has been added successfully" every time the textboxes get validated and submitted and want to clear that label after submission. Is there any way to do that?

```
protected void BtnThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            LabelThread.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
            LabelThread.Text = "Thread has been added successfully";
        }

        else
        {

            LabelThread.Text = "Thread couldnot not be added";

        }

        Thread obj = new Thread();
        obj.Insert_thread = TxtBoxThread.Text;

        int j = obj.insertmethod();

        TxtBoxThread.Text = "";
```

Comment: What Thread Class are you using? System.Threading.Thread() does not accept 0 parameters. Seems you are trying to access a control on a Thread that is not in the Main UI Thread. Is the button doing a postback? If so, The label should update.

Comment: I have made my own thread class which inserts data into the database

Comment: Do you get an error message? Is it the Label or the Textbox you want to clear? Looks ok until it reaches your custom thread object. If so, maybe you should post your custom thread code.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Its just that I want to show the text in the label only when data is submitted and added in to the database. Once The data has been added It shows the message on the label and clears the text box. but next time when the user does not provide any data into the text box, i want that label to not show that message "Thread has been added successfully" .

Comment: public class Thread
    {
       Clssqlconnection obj = new Clssqlconnection();

        public string Insert_thread { get; set; }

        public int insertmethod()
        {

            obj.str = @"insert into [Add_thread] (Insert_thread)" +
                 "values('" + Insert_thread + "')";
            return obj.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}

Comment: I would go by validating an empty field at the begining (show message and exit function) and then adding the try..catch block inside your thread class and if it fails it throws an exception back to another try..catch in your code behind which would show the exception message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing to a element that has no ViewState.  I believe that its contents will not persist across post backs, and will only appear immediately after setting it.

ASPX:

```
<div id="MessageBox" runat="server"></div>
```

In your BtnThread_Click event:

```
MessageBox.InnerText = "Thread has been added successfully";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
   {

    }
   LabelThread.Text = String.Empty;
}
```